# Angular mat label & input side by side

Tags: html, css, angular

how to have the mat-label and the input side by side? I also need it to be in column because I have several inputs but I can't get the label and the input side by side.

thanks.

**html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">

<div class="form-nom">
  <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
    <mat-label>Nom</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControl="nom">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

</form>
```

**css**

```
form {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.form-nom {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<div>
  <label>Float label: </label>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput />
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: works for me , here is working example [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k7z1gc?file=src/app/form-field-label-example.html) , If that's not what you are looking for, please elaborate more will be more than happy to help you